# "redefinition" error changes to "differs in levels of indirection" when using `auto` keyword

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++-2012

C++11 has been introduced to me as :

> C++11 introduces several new handy-dandy type inference capabilities
>   that mean you can spend less time having to write out things the
>   compiler already knows

**Question:** Why compiler have different behavior toward two below errors ? And Isn't it *provocative in such simple cases*?

```
class Foo{};
class Bar{};
int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    auto foo = Foo();       // <- error C2086: 'Foo foo' : redefinition
    ////////////
    Bar* boo = new Bar();
    auto boo = new Bar();   // <- error C2040: 'boo' : 'auto' differs in levels of indirection from 'Bar *'

    return 0;
}
```

PS: I forget to tell my compiler: It's VS2012

Comment: Er... even `int main() { int a; int a; }` is an error, you can't have *any* redeclaration of a local variable. Can you give an example that better demonstates what you're trying to ask?

Comment: From my point of view, both has same error. the `redefinition`. I say that because I know if a use `foo1`, `foo2`, `boo1`, `boo2` there will be no error. @Mat

Comment: Sorry I misread. Anyhow, I'm not sure what your point is. If you want to file a diagnostics bug with Microsoft, go ahead

Comment: @Mat: It's much easier to post here about such a thing than to file a bug report with MicroSoft. This is probably a bug in MSVC, and it looks like the OP wanted to hear our opinions on that hypothesis. Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, the error is that an object of the same type is redefined. Redefinitions are illegal an the compilers reports that.

Every definition is also a declaration. Obviously, the compiler finds that your second definition is a declaration of the name `boo` but the declaration actually differs from the first one and the compiler reports this error. It may never get to the point of determining that the incorrect declaration also happens to be definition and there is, thus, also a redefinition.

Your expectation that compilers shall report the same error if there are multiple issues with the code is somewhat unrelatistic as it is probably possible to create examples which where one use would need to produce multiple different errors.

Comment: This is doublespeak! You are saying that the compiler detects a redefinition error, but never gets around to determining that it is a redefinition error.

Comment: @TonyK No, he's saying the compiler quit reporting errors with that line after diagnosing that the redeclaration is of a different type. Anyway, the last paragraph is the most pertinent one.

Comment: @TonyK: Actually, I explicitly stated "It may never get to the point of determining ... that the incorrect declaration also happens to be ... a redefinition". I don't think there is any double-speak.

Comment: @Praetorian: But the second definition is not a different type is it? It's a `Bar*`, just like the first one.

Comment: @TonyK: I don't have the standard available in a suitably searchable way (typing on a mobile device) but having only differing declarations is considered to be an error by [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/), too, as can be seen [here](http://ideone.com/2fz8A1).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in the compiler's error-reporting code.

The error message that I get for the first redefinition `auto foo = Foo();` is `error C2371: 'foo': redefinition; different basic types`, which is wrong: the types of both `foo`'s are the same.

The error message for the second redefinition is wrong too, just differently wrong.

So just another MicroSoft cock-up.